# Using Box2D in Cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am trying to add a box2d on my current project in cocos2dx, I am using an ubuntu for my os and clion for my ide. everything was working but **I can't use box2d**

> Box2D/Box2D.h No such file or directory

I tried to set this

```
option(USE_CHIPMUNK "Use chipmunk for physics library" OFF)
option(USE_BOX2D "Use box2d for physics library" ON)
```

and got this error

> chipmunk.h: No such file or directory

Tried also to disable PHYSICS on **cocos2d/cocos/base/ccConfig.h**

```
#ifndef CC_USE_PHYSICS
#define CC_USE_PHYSICS 0
#endif
```

And I can't run the project with this error only

```
Error running command, return code: 2.
```

**using cocos2d-x v3 from github**

FULL SOURCE CODE JUST TO TEST IF IT WORKS

```
#ifndef __HELLOWORLD_SCENE_H__
#define __HELLOWORLD_SCENE_H__

#include "cocos2d.h"
#include "Box2D/Box2D.h"

class HelloWorld : public cocos2d::Layer
{
public:
    // there's no 'id' in cpp, so we recommend returning the class instance pointer
    static cocos2d::Scene* createScene();

    // Here's a difference. Method 'init' in cocos2d-x returns bool, instead of returning 'id' in cocos2d-iphone
    virtual bool init();

    // a selector callback
    void menuCloseCallback(cocos2d::Ref* pSender);

    // implement the "static create()" method manually
    CREATE_FUNC(HelloWorld);
};

#endif // __HELLOWORLD_SCENE_H__
```

Comment: Does the sample Cocos2d-x app compile OK?

Comment: Yes. I Just can't manage to make it work with box2d. tried changing to #include <Box2D/Box2D.h> since in other samples, but still not working

Comment: That's strange as `external/` is added to the include path by default, so that should work.

Comment: I tried to run the test file of cocos and looks like box2d is disabled since it is not included in the sample list

Comment: Yeah I looked into using Box2D instead of Chipmunk, but it's not simply a case of turning off one and turning on the other.  The `PhysicsBody` class, for example, only works with Chipmunk.  What is the reason you want to use Box2D?

Comment: I am more familiar in Box2d, The game was originally written using libGDX, as I want to avoid jvm, and this is just the first time I incountered chipmunk. is chipmunk better than box2d?

Comment: Better performance wise, yes.  You can use it via `PhysicsBody` rather than directly, which makes using it much simpler.  I think the only thing it doesn't have is Continuous Collision Detection, but to be honest I'm not even sure if that's important or not.

Comment: hmm.looks great. I'll take a look and read more about chipmunk and try implement this rather than Box2d. Thanks

Comment: Were you able to figure this out ? I upgraded from 3.13.1 to 3.17, and I have the same problem.